# Typescript property doesnot exist

Tags: typescript, angular5

I am working on the dropdown menu list.

```
this[dropdownName] = Object.entries(value).map(a => {
     console.log(a);
     return a[1].prvid + ' - '+ a[0];
})
```

With above code at console I get result as below

```
[0: "xyz" 
 1: {prvid: 11}]
```

I need to return a[1].prvid concat with a[0].

But I receive typescript error as:

```
[ts] Property 'prvid' does not exist on type '{}'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently TypeScript [type inference](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html) can't figure out what type `a[1]` is, or rather it thinks it has, but it thinks it's `{}` (which has no `prvid` property). You'll need to add the necessary [type annotations](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html) to tell TypeScript what type `a[1]` is (probably by telling it what `a` is).

Comment: For now I did Object.entries(value).map((a: any)=>...

Is that correct method?

Comment: @SS - Ideally, no, `any` basically tells TypeScript not to do type checking on that parameter. Ideally, you have a type for the entries in `a` (which sounds like it would need to be a [union or intersection type](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html), and then declare `a` as an array of that type.